# android studio cannot reference @color and @mipmap

Tags: android, reference

`Android Studio` cannot find my resources, on other projects android studio works fine.

[image: Android studio Suggestion]

Here is a image of my `resources` in `values` folder.
[image: Resources image]

Comment: Put the actual code in your answer, not links to screenshots

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background=""
        />

Comment: background  hint “no suggestion"

Comment: **1** - your resources sholudn't reside in `mipmap`, but in `drawable`. **2** - create the missing folders.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to Rebuild your project once. From `Build Menu > Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 0):

Make res folders inside made values folder and then place your xml colors.xml in this folder